# Type erasure for parent class

Tags: java, generics

I had a class declared as

```
class Heap extends ArrayList<Element>
```

For some reason I needed to make it generic as

```
class Heap<HeapImpl extends Heap> extends ArrayList<Element>
```

However, I still have legacy code where variables are declared simply as

```
Heap heap;
```

For these variables the parent's generic type is erased and it's given simply as `ArrayList<Object>`. Why does it happen?

Comment: I have no idea how the class is used but I can’t help wondering why it extends ArrayList? Wouldn’t it be better to declare it `class Heap<Element>` only and let the ArrayList be an internal container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the behavior for generics written without a type parameter. You should at least transform your legacy code into someting like Heap.

For more détails on that see the langage spec

UPDATE :

Here's a test, i do not seem to got what you described

```
package generics;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

public class HeapTest {

public static class Heap<T> extends ArrayList<String> {}

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Heap h = new Heap<>();
        Type sc = h.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        assertTrue(sc instanceof ParameterizedType);

        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) sc;
        assertEquals(1, pt.getActualTypeArguments().length);

        assertSame(String.class, pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);

        Class<?> clazz              = (Class<?>) pt.getRawType();
        Method method               = clazz.getMethod("get", int.class);

        TypeVariable<?> rt          = (TypeVariable<?>) method.getGenericReturnType();
        String name                 = rt.getName();

        Class<?> arrayListClass     = (Class<?>) pt.getRawType();

        int i = 0;
        for (TypeVariable<?> tv : arrayListClass.getTypeParameters()) {
            if (tv.getName() == name) {
                break;
            }
            i ++;
        }

        Type actualReturnType       = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[i];
        assertSame(String.class, actualReturnType);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also seeing your snippet i assume you want somewhere to return the real type and not Heap. Although possible, using generics un such case may be an anti-pattern.

Comment: I can't find it in the language spec. It only says that "A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments", but a raw type here is 'Heap' which is still 'ArrayList<Element>' even without parametrization. I can't find any explicit mention that using raw type causes type erasure on parent class or makes parent class raw as well. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Your legacy code executes in a separate jvm ? Please give more sample code

Comment: It's legacy more in a sense that it was written before I had an idea that this class should be generic. In fact it was written by me about 2 weeks ago and I'm perfectly capable of refactoring all instances of variables declared as raw type into generic type. And what I did in the end was actually getting rid of a generic. So I'm asking for a help not with this particular use case, but to understand this behavior of a compiler because I can't find where it's specified.

Comment: Hi, no i didn't. Thanks for the notice, I see your point. It's even possible to write `Heap h = new Heap();` and the test will still succeed. But the type of return value of `h.get(0)` is `Object`, not `String`. That's what I can't understand.

Comment: This is because to obtain the method via reflection you use the raw type. Getting the concrete return type is possible but super complicated to figure out, you have to make some mapping. Here's another update that shows it.